# Android : Animation and interpolatedTime

Tags: android, animation, interpolation

I've  a list view of text data. Initially all the rows are of fixed size even if the text occupies more space. In case, the complete text is not visible, the row gets expanded on click.
To implement this expansion, I create an animation class extending the Animation. And in the applyTransformation method , I'm trying to use interpolatedTime (input ) to gradually expand the row to give a nice feeling.

```
if (interpolatedTime < 1.0f) {
    params.height = (int) ((params.height - mainTextParams1.height) *
    interpolatedTime);

    maintxtlayout.setLayoutParams(params);
    mAnimatedView.requestLayout();

} else if (!mWasEndedAlready) {
    maintxtlayout.setLayoutParams(params);
    mAnimatedView.requestLayout();
    mWasEndedAlready = true;
}
```

However , the problem I'm facing is that it seems that methods is getting called only twice. First with the interpolatedTime having value = 0.0 and next time with value = 1.0 .

I tried to extend LinearInterpolator , and extended its getInterpolation method to increase value by 0.05f but that method is also getting called only twice once with 0 and second time with 1.

I also tried AccelerateInterpolator, but with that also the same problem.

What is it that I'm missing here?

thanks
pradeep

Comment: Is the duration of the animation big enough? I suspect a duration of 0 would cause this behaviour...

Comment: I have set duration as 1000L .